# Is there a name for an equality of the like $\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\mathbb{P}(A_n\mid A_{n-1})\cdots\mathbb{P}(A_2\mid A_{1})\mathbb{P}(A_1)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be some specific events in $\Omega$. I am currently reading a quite technical paper which at one points states essentially that for a specific given event $A_n$ we have

$$\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\mathbb{P}(A_n\mid A_{n-1})\cdots\mathbb{P}(A_2\mid A_{1})\mathbb{P}(A_1)$$

where $\mathbb{P}(A_k\mid A_l) = 1$ for all $k \leq l$, and all $A_n$s depend on the presented context in the paper. Right now I am not sure how much the claimed equality depends on the said context, and how much it is just basic probability theory. The equality does seem a bit familiar, but I am not exactly sure what it is. So my questions are that 1.) is there some general probability theoretic way of concluding such an equality for events with positive probability and 2.) if not, does such special cases have some well-known name?

Comment: from Bayes' theorem, $\mathbb P(B)=\mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(A)/\mathbb P(A\mid B)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Dammit, I knew the equation looked too familiar! This shows that you definitely do lose equation manipulation muscles over time if you don't practice them regularly. Thanks!